# Arrays of Structures and External Files in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

poSo, I've made some progress with a question I asked earlier, but I have one more question.  I'll copy and paste the description of the assignment from my earlier question: So I'm working on a homework assignment for my CS162 class which requires me to make a program that allows the user to input their class plan for college. The user inputs classes they have taken, are currently taken, and/or plan on taking, with the categories of: department/class number, class name, term/year, whether or not the class is required for their major, and any additional comments. Then, the program is supposed to store this invermation with external data files so that the classes are stored and won't be lost. The program should be able to store up to 60 classes in memory.

Now, I've set up everything correctly (I believe) with my arrays of structures; but what I'm still struggling with is the reading of this information into an external file to be stored.  Here's what I have so far:

```
struct college_class
{
    string dept_classnumber;
    string class_name;
    string term_year;
    string is_required;
    string comments;
    string grade;
}
college_class myCollegeClass[60];

int main()
{
    int i=0;'
    char again='y';
    while(again != 'n' && again != 'N' && i<60)
    {
        cout<<"Enter department and class number (e.g. "CS162"): ";
        getline (cin,my CollegeClass[n].dept_classnumber);
        cout<<"Enter class name (e.g. "Intro to Computer Science"): ";
        getline (cin,myCollegeClass[n].class_name);
        cout<<"Enter the term and year the class was/will be taken: ";
        getline (cin, myCollegeClass[n].term_year;
        cout<<"Enter whether or not this class is required for your major: ";
        getline (cin,myCollegeClass[n].is_required);
        cout<<"Enter any additional comments here: ";
        getline (cin, myCollegeClass[n].comments);
        cout<<"Would you like to enter another class?(y/n)";
        cin>>again;
        i++;
    }
    ofstream myfile("classes");
    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
        /*I know that I need to loop through my myCollegeClass here, but I'm not sure how to do it*/
        {
            myfile<<myCollegeClass[i].dept_classnumber;
            myfile<<myCollegeClass[i].class_name;
            myfile<<myCollegeClass[i].term_year;
            myfile<<myCollegeClass[i].is_required;
            myfile<<myCollegeClass[i].comments;
        }
    }
    else cout<<"Unable to open file";
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help me with the external file aspect of this?  Thanks so much for the help (in advance)

Comment: A big problem is that you don't write lines, so all texts will be inalonglinelikethis. When you solve that, just read it line by line.

Comment: And if you don't know how to loop from zero to the number of items you actually have in the array, then you need to go back to study the basic statements again.

Comment: And finally, you currently write from index `i` of the array, but that index is one beyond what you actually have entered. So that structure contain no data.

Comment: I know how and I've done it before; it's just late and I'm blanking out here.  Do you have a link or something that can show that basic process?  And yeah, I need to add endl - thanks for the reminder.

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) { myfile << myCollegeClass[j]..... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to change your variable from `n` which doesn't apper anywhere to `i` in your while loop.

From this:

```
getline (cin,my CollegeClass[n].dept_classnumber);
```

to this:

```
getline (cin,my CollegeClass[i].dept_classnumber);
```

Secondly add a for loop to save every class. The loop should look like this:

```
for(int j=0;j<i;++j){
        myfile<<myCollegeClass[j].dept_classnumber<<endl;
        myfile<<myCollegeClass[j].class_name<<endl;
        myfile<<myCollegeClass[j].term_year<<endl;
        myfile<<myCollegeClass[j].is_required<<endl;
        myfile<<myCollegeClass[j].comments<<endl;
}
```

Don't forget to close the file with:

```
myfile.close();
```

Futhermore you should name your variable with names that say for what purpose they are used.
Here you can change `i` to `numberOfClasses` it woudl look much better.